# Is there a common work around for not being able to extend multiple classes, and interfaces that cant have private information?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, interface

I have an object A. I also have objects B,C,D that use to extend A. I now decided I want A to have its data, but also optionally have data that exists in B C and D. Obviously you can't extend multiple classes, and interface can't have private data so they can't be used here.

Ideally I would have this implemented:

```
public class E extends A implements B, D
```

So that it contains all of A, B, and D but not C.

Also, the person implementing would also extends a `Handle<T extends A>` class so that the new data can be processed correctly.

The biggest problem here is that the one unique variable in B C and D is then lost if they become interfaces.

Comment: Shouldn't you try to find a better pattern than this particular style of implementation?

Comment: I'd use exactly that line of code you have there.  There really aren't any other solutions.  If you have a framework and can't refactor those types -- I dunno... God help you, and pick less crappy frameworks.

Comment: Use _composition_: `E` "is `A`" and, additionally, "has `B` and `D`".

Comment: @JeromeAnthony The problem is I really wanted the A class to have a baseline, but also be modular by implementing those classes.

Comment: Dude, too many classes there. Are you sure class E is not violating more than one solid principle?

Comment: @dierre, I am not sure I understand your question.

Comment: markspace, It made sense when they all extended A, but I wanted implementers to be able to select one or more since they're not dependent on each other.

Comment: Which version of Java are you thinking?

Comment: @JeromeAnthony any version.

Comment: Generally speaking, to me, extends A + implements B + implements C sounds not that good your class E is doing many things. Also, if you say "also *optionally* have data that exists in B,C and D" I would say you should think of using composition as a pattern.